# IONIC 5 How to reload the page without white screen

Tags: javascript, angular, ionic-framework

When I implemented it on the IONIC 5 application, my problem was that every time I reloaded the page, it would show the spinner and image I had set, but after the spinner was completely reloaded, the application would show a white screen for 1 to 2 seconds and then only show the page I wanted.

So, my question is how can I reload the page without the white screen show?

I have set the codes below in my app.component.html, so every time my app reload the page, it will show the spinner and image

```
<ion-app>
  <ion-router-outlet></ion-router-outlet>
  <div class="loading-overlay" *ngIf="loading" style="margin: auto;">
    <img src="assets/icon/favicon.png"style="height:150px;width:150px;"/> <br/>
    <!-- Bubbles Spinner -->
    <ion-spinner name="bubbles"></ion-spinner>&nbsp;
    <span>Please Wait..</span>
  </div>
</ion-app>
```

the function in my app.component.ts

```
  constructor(private router: Router,
              private so: ScreenOrientation,
              private alertCtrl: AlertController,
              private platform: Platform,
              private _location: Location,
              ) {
   this.router.events.subscribe((e : RouterEvent) => {
      this.navigationInterceptor(e);
    })


    this.router.events.subscribe((event) => {
        if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
          this.history.push(event.urlAfterRedirects)
        }
    })


   //Updated Code

  this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      setTimeout(function(){
        this.splashScreen.hide();
      }, 50);
    });
  }
  // Shows and hides the loading spinner during RouterEvent changes
  navigationInterceptor(event: RouterEvent): void {
    if (event instanceof NavigationStart) {
      this.loading = true
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
      this.loading = false
    }

    // Set loading state to false in both of the below events to hide the spinner in case a request fails
    if (event instanceof NavigationCancel) {
      this.loading = false
    }
    if (event instanceof NavigationError) {
      this.loading = false
    }
  }
```

Below is one of the codes that how I reload my page:

```
this.router.navigate(['/order'])
                .then(() => {
                  window.location.reload();
                });
```

Comment: try to add platform.isReady and splashScreen hide after 500ms

Comment: @Indraraj26 Hi, I have updated my code under constructor function, but it seems doesn't work

Comment: Why are you trying to reload the page? Do you need the HTML to update to new values? Or something else?

Answer (score 2):

if this code in your app.component.ts , then add this

```
initializeApp() {
this.platform.ready().then(() => {

  this.splashScreen.hide();

})
```

and in your config.xml

```
 <preference name="SplashScreenDelay" value="3000" />
```

note the value could change based on your app

or if the the code was in page you can add the code to your constructor ,

or you can change the value of `setTimeout` function to bigger number ( like 500, 1000 ... etc )